# How can I iterate through the keys of a dictionary based on condition?

Tags: python, loops

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

def iteration(reg=None):
    for k in dic.keys():
        print('x')

iteration(reg='a')
iteration(reg='all')
```

I am trying to loop through the keys in a dictionary on two different conditions, one when the key is equal to a specific value and the other one is through all keys by denoting 'all' to the argument of the function.

I can go through the first condition by using if k == 'a' (example) but not sure what to pass for the second condition

Comment: It will make more sense instead of `all` to simply not pass argumet. Also iterating over one key doesn't make sense at all - this is dict.

Comment: What is your expected output in each case? What do you expect to get when you iterate a single key?

Comment: First, your `iteration()` function should really take a dictionary as an argument, not rely on a global variable. Second, a dictionary's keys must be unique, so it wouldn't make sense to even bother iterating if you want to use a specific key, just do `d["a"]` or `d[reg]` if `reg is not None`. Third, you don't need to call the `.keys()` method, as dictionaries already return an iterator over their keys, so you just need `for k in d:`.

Comment: In my original code, the key itself is the name of the register in an IC. I will pass the key to read the value of that particular register.

Comment: I understand that iterating over a single key does not make sense in the usual scenarios, but in my case it does.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Do you need to do something with every value in your dictionary in both cases, but just also want to be able to do something special if `reg` isn't `"all"`?

Comment: If `reg` is `None` iterate through all keys, else get the specific key. Something like this: https://ideone.com/V2QC5T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. I understand that this was a very particular case which did not make sense to a lot of them. But I happened to have the need to do exactly as described in the original question.

I was able to figure out a way to do it and this is how I did it.

```
def iteration(reg, regDict):
   string1 = 'all'
   if reg.casefold() == string1.casefold():
       reglist = [*regDict]
   else:
       reglist = [reg]

for k in reglist:
   do this
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `filter` function and a lambda expression:

```py
for key in filter(lambda k: k == "a", dic):
    print("x")
```

You can use this method to filter several things depending on the function you pass into `filter`, in my example I am filtering out every key that does not equal `"a"`. You can use it to make a wrapper that has the functionality you specify by using a check like so:

```py
def iteration(dic, func="all"):
    return filter(func, dic) if func != "all" else filter(None, dic)

for key in iteration(dic, lambda k: k == "a"):
    print("x")
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny edited to swap variable names, and to answer second part of the question. As for efficiency, that is a function of the problem, not my solution...